# IntelliJ IDEA, editor tabs jumping

Tags: tabs, intellij-idea, editor

I use IntelliJ IDEA v12.0.4

If I open a lot of tabs with documents - tabs placed as few rows.
Row of tabs with selected tab - always bottom.
So if I chose a tab from the top row - this row "jumps" to bottom.

Such jumps are very uncomfortable. How to disable it?

Comment: Nearly 5 years later and it's still not fixed. Annoying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22546), please vote.

Answer (score 2):

There is an very old Idea open issue regarding this.
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22546
You could vote it.

I was taken into account a suggestion of one of its commenters. His suggestion is to place the editor tabs on right (or left) side of the IDE (if you have a wide screen).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Under Editor->Editor Tabs select show tabs in single row.

[image]

Comment: I wanna have multiple rows... But they should not jump

Comment: And I wanna have ten million dollars on my account. :) You get what you get.

Comment: ))))) Maybe a plugin exists? Very simple feature, but idea lacks it